# JavaFX styling broken after upgrade from Java 7

Tags: javafx, java-8, java-7

After upgrading from Java 7 to Java 8, we are seeing some styling issues in a "legacy" (read: I didn't write it and have no real good experience with JavaFX) application. After multiple attempts to troubleshoot this in Scene Builder (again, no real experience there, please bear with me), I am hoping to get some pointers here.

The image below illustrates the two issues we are seeing with text boxes, buttons, and choice boxes. One, the text box has lost the rounded corner styling (which isn't crucial, but I would like to understand the reason). Two, when hovering over any of the elements, they are covered with a white box, which will eventually disappear after moving the mouse away again and/or clicking somewhere else.

[image: JavaFX upgrade issues]

The application uses several stylesheets and I am not sure which ones are relevant. Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is in one or more of your stylesheets, so SceneBuilder will not be any help. Try using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to debug the styles.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. While I see changes happening in the ScenicView UI on hover, I do not see anything that looks like a white box being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Between Java 7 and Java 8 there was a switch between the new default style called modena and the old one called caspian. Your old css code is probably written against the old caspian style sheet and it is possible that your code is just not valid when applied to the new modena style. What you can try is to use the old default style by providing this property `-Djavafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl=caspian` on the command line and then see whether your old css works again. I am not sure it will work but it is worth a try.

Comment: Adding the JVM option, definitely is an improvement. However, the white box still comes up when clicking on a node. It does disappear faster now though, when clicking around or hovering over other elements.